# Passing temporary object to function

Tags: c++, object, parameter-passing

I THINK this is called a temporary object. Here is my scenario:

I have some functions:

```
void List<T>::Remove(ListIterator &)
ListIterator List<T>::Begin() //returns an iterator pointing to the first node in the list.
```

In G++ when I try to do something like this:

```
mylist.Remove(mylist.Begin())
```

I get the following error:

no matching function for call to Remove(ListIterator).

I don't have a function that takes a ListIterator by value and nor do I want one. However I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do even makes sense. The code works on windows VS2012 but not in g++.

Any advice on how to either fix my implementation or an explanation of this behaviour is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you make it take a const & instead?

Comment: @doctorlove Or even pass by value.  Iterators (at least STL compliant iterators) should normally be designed so that copy is extremely cheap.

Comment: Indeed, I just wondered about it saying List<T> rather than list<T> so wondered if something "not "STL compliant" was going on

Comment: None of it is stl compliant, it's essentially just an exercise and these are all homebrewed classes. ListIterator is a friend of List so List can modify ListIterator. I wanted to be able to modify the list and then be able to continue using the iterator afterwards, which is why I wanted to pass it by reference

Answer (score 1):

The results of `mylist.Begin()` are a temporary (unless
`mylist.Begin()` returns a reference).  You can't use
a temporary to initialize a non-const reference.  Either assign
the results to a variable, and pass it to `Remove`, make the
reference const, or use pass by value.

As to why VS2012 compiles it: VS2012 isn't conform.

Answer (score 0):

Kris, if you see the error compiler gave (in your first message) "no matching function for call to Remove(ListIterator)" here the compiler states the ListIterator is passed to Remove as parameter whereas it expects ListIterator&,  so to resolve change the func declaration Begin to return ListIterator& , or as Kris suggested, change Remove func declaration to take const ListIterator & as parameter. I hope both options should work.